# Facebook messenger account linking

Tags: python, bots, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I was able to get the callback with the redirect_uri and auth code and I was able to authorize the user and redirect him but I am not getting the account_linking in the request object after successful login ie.., I want to check whether the user is logged in or not for every message he sends.

Answer (score 0):

The account linking feature does not support this type of token validation. You would need to send a request to your auth server to check if the person is still logged in.

Comment: What if user clicks the logout button, I mean it doesnt send any request to my server before logging off and how would my auth server knows that the user has logged out